# ISRegSpy error on Image Build that contains a VFP / COM / OlePublic DLL

Tags: installshield, visual-foxpro, visual-foxpro-9

I created a [VFP OlePulic class](https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/vfpdotnetinterop/aspcominterop.aspx#:%7E:text=to%20the%20developer.-,calling%20com%20components%20from%20.net,-Calling%20COM%20components) and when I use install shield 5 that comes w/ VFP 9, I'm getting the following error on building my install shield package.  I suspect this is why my dll isn't getting registered on install of said package.

Running on Windows 10 (is that the problem?).

> ISRegSpy detects following module 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AcLayers.dll' hooked into this process, which will cause ISRegspy to malfunction.
> You need to shut the application down and restart COM extraction.

[image: screenshot of install shield build error]

Comment: See https://doughennig.com/Papers/Pub/InnoSetup.pdf which is the state of the debate in the Fox community if you ask me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried an uninstall & re-install but no luck.

I ended up deleting some folders in `My Documents` for install shield projects & a few registry entries & it magically started working again.

Not sure which thing I deleted fixed it.  I’m guessing something in my documents.